# Stuck at systemd startup screen + flickering once a second after upgrading to 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd, do-release-upgrade, flicker

I have just finished upgrading to 18.04 from 17.10 using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

then rebooted only to find that it cannot boot up again.

When I try to boot, it goes well until the systemd message:

```
Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.files...tem changes.pp link was shut down...
```

where it starts flickering and stays there.

I tried older kernel versions, but the same thing happened. I also tried adding some boot parameters `amdgpu.dc=0`(from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032198/632192)) and `nomodeset`, but those only stopped the backlight from flickering with the display.

GPUs:

0:Intel HD Graphics 520

1:AMD Radeon R5 M330

**UPDATE:**
I was able to disable `gdm3` and make `lightdm` the default DM. Now it gets to LightDM, but it will never get to GNOME; it just loops (login loop).
At least now I am sure the cause of the flickering is `gdm3`.
Note: I tried `gdm3` under both Wayland and X11, by editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, but the only difference was that with X11 I couldn't even see the systemd messages.

Comment: See the answer under this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031511/cant-disable-nouveau-drivers-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Please could you described how you managed to do that? I am having the same issue :(