# Upgrade to latest Ubuntu cannot boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04, macbook-pro

My upgrade got stuck on this screen. This is the message that is flickering over and over again:

[image]

I can get into recovery mode, but I'm not sure how to fix this problem. It is on a dual boot MacBook pro (Intel Iris GPU).

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032418/stuck-at-systemd-startup-screen-flickering-once-a-second-after-upgrading-to-18, none of the "solutions" worked though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing from a USB drive over the existing installation should have  fixed it, but the install process froze and I needed to re-start it, e.g. frozen here:[image]
Then I could go to the partitioning step and select my ext4, editing it to mount to root (avoiding the default option to wipe everything) and now I get a login prompt but the password is not accepted.
[Ubuntu with full disk encryption - bad password after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031302/ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-bad-password-after-upgrade-to-18-04) but the solution presented there doesn't work. Ended up having to re-install everything, wiping my existing system. Good thing that all my stuff is in the cloud. The fresh install works flawlessly.