# GNOME does not show the option to use dedicated graphics card on right click

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, gnome-shell, hybrid-graphics

I have recently fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 after the upgrade from 17.10 failed (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032418/stuck-at-systemd-startup-screen-flickering-once-a-second-after-upgrading-to-18) for more about that), and now the option to use dedicated graphics card does not show up when I right-click any icon.

Setting global variable `DRI_PRIME` does make a command use the dedicated Radeon R5 M330, so I am sure that there are no driver related issues. However, the dedicated GPU does not show up in the Details section in System Settings; only the integrated Intel HD Graphics 520 shows up. It used to show up there as "AMD HAINAN" when using the `radeon` driver, and "amd radeon r5 m330" when using the `amdgpu` driver.

**How can I make the "Use Dedicated Graphics Card" option appear in the drop-down menu when right-clicking an application icon?**

**EDIT:** I found this line in `sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell` (it is the first line in the log):

```
May 11 14:02:31 yassine-HP-Notebook gnome-shell[1164]: Ignoring GPU /dev/dri/card1 due to the lack of connectors
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNOME requires `switcheroo-control` in order to detect whether the system has a hybrid graphics configuration. Check [this](http://www.hadess.net/2016/10/dual-gpu-integration-in-gnome.html) for more on that.

The fix was as easy as running one command:
`sudo apt install switcheroo-control`, and once it was installed, everything worked as expected, so the "Use dedicated graphics card" appeared in the right-click menu, and the GPU showed up in System Settings. It did not require a reboot or restarting the session.

I still wonder why this package was not installed during the Ubuntu installation...