# Ubuntu 18.04: nvidia PRIME issue - prime-select intel does not work

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intel, nvidia-prime

I have a strange problem while using nvidia-prime comand. When I change the command prime-select like this

```
prime-select intel
```

and reboot the system, my laptop will display something like this and will result with endless loop with displaying information on screenshot below:

[image: error]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: a quick workaround if You are in a hurry to use ubuntu for work...alt+f2 to get into tty, login there and type sudo prime-select nvidia, after reboot You may further search for solutions with intel, good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, with that error, you can't access any tty. You should reboot in rescue mode from GRUB, enter in the shell as root and run `prime-select nvidia`. Then follow my answer. I'm quite sure is the same exact problem.

Comment: Hi, 

I did that with running ubuntu via recovery mode and then dpkg. I'm wondering how to make nvidia-prime packet to work correctly.

Comment: If you're running in Xorg, it should be working.

Comment: I mean I changed that parameter to 

    prime-select nvidia

and it works, but the point is I want to use my integrated intel card.

Comment: Then, follow the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Got my same problem. You should switch to Xorg. I think is a 18.04 Wayland bug.

My gdm3 session was running in wayland. To check it:

```
 $ loginctl
 SESSION     UID  USER     SEAT     TTY             
       2    1000  velix    seat0    tty2            
      c2    1000  velix                                             
      c1     120  gdm      seat0    tty1
```

The command `loginctl show-session <session-n> -p Type` show the session type:

```
$ loginctl show-session c1 -p Type
Type=Wayland
```

To change it, edit the file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncomment the line `WaylandEnable=false`.

After rebooting:

```
$ loginctl show-session c1 -p Type
Type=x11
```

See [My question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031511/cant-disable-nouveau-drivers-in-ubuntu-18-04) for a little more details.